# Removing rows causes "row.names" column to appear when displayed with View()

Tags: r

To remove rows from a data frame, I use the following command:

```
data <- data[-1, ]
```

for example to remove the first row. I need to remove the first 6 rows, so I used the following:

```
data <- data[-c(1,2,3,4,5,6), ]
```

OR

```
data <- data[-(1:6), ]
```

this works as far as removing the row names, but introduced a new column called `row.names` that I cannot get rid of unless I use the command:

```
row.names(data) <- NULL
```

What is the reason for this? Is there a better way of removing a number of rows/columns with one command?

Example:
[image]

after the following code:

```
tquery <- tquery[-(1:6), ]
```

This is the data:
[image]

Comment: Don't vote to close - OP has discovered a gotcha with `View()` on dataframes.

Comment: Is this a "gotcha" if it is clearly documented in a (very short) help file? `If there are row names on the data frame that are not 1:nrow, they are displayed in a separate first column called row.names.`

Comment: Another issue with `View()` under RStudio: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19341853/r-view-does-not-display-all-columns-of-data-frame

Comment: I hate `View` for other reasons: `mat1 <- \`colnames<-\`(matrix(1:10, 5, 2), c('x','y')); mat2 <- \`colnames<-\`(matrix(11:20, 5, 2), c('x','y')); View(cbind(mat1, mat2)); rownames(mat1) <- rownames(mat2) <- letters[1:5]; View(cbind(mat1, mat2))` With NULL rownames, it binds as expected. With non NULL rownames, the first occurrence is just repeated. It appears as expected in the console. wtf `View`?

Comment: `print.data.frame` and `View` are not intended to do the same thing (as per the description of each), IMO, and one could easily be fixed to be identical to the other.. but they are not

Comment: It seems like my above comment is also an rstudio bug since this behavior does not occur in my terminal

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Although it seems as such, you are not actually adding a column to the data.  What you are seeing is just a result of using `View()`.  The function is showing the "row.names" attribute of the data frame as the first column, but you didn't really add the column.

This is expected and documented behavior.  From the **Details** section of `help(View)`

> If there are row names on the data frame that are not `1:nrow`, they are displayed in a separate first column called `row.names`.

So since you subsetted the data, the row names are technically **not** `1:nrow` any more and hence the new column is introduced in the viewer.

Print your data in the console and you'll see the difference.

```
View(mtcars) ## because the mtcars row names are not 1:nrow
```

versus

```
mtcars
```

Basically, don't trust `View()` to display an exact representation of the actual data.  Instead use `attributes()`, `*names()`, `dim()`, `length()`, etc. or just peek at the data with `head()`.

Comment: Ok, but admittedly it is a gotcha with `View()` and is a good catch.

Answer (score 2):

See r help via "?row.names" for more info. From the documentation, "All data frames have a row names attribute"

```
?row.names ## get more information about row.names from r help
```

row.names is not a new column, but rather an attribute of every single data frame. This is simply meta data and is ignored by most data. When you output this data (i.e. CSV) or use it in a function, this data will not interfere. This is similar to how excel has row numbers on the left margin, which is referential data for the application.

```
str(your_dataframe) ## see that those columns don't exist
colnames(your_dataframe) ## see column names
```