# View() an entire dataset in RStudio (past 1000 row limit)

Tags: r

Simple question but I can't figure it out in RStudio:
`View(mydata)` only gives me 1000 rows.

How can I increase this limit to a number of my choosing?  Say, like 25,000?

Comment: Are you using the plain RGui, or RStudio?  I think the 1000 row limitation is built into RStudio, but they may increase it depending on demand from the community.  See this SO post for more information: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19341853/r-view-does-not-display-all-columns-of-data-frame

Comment: OK, thanks.  I'm using R Studio.

Comment: RStudio - Version 0.99.235 - has "infinite scroll", so you can view all the data.

Comment: @zx8754 the latest version I see on their site is 0.98.1102

Comment: @DavidArenburg see the answer, sorry, yes it is a preview version.

Comment: yes you have to go and download the preview/beta version.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

RStudio preview version - [Version 0.99.235](http://www.rstudio.com/products/rstudio/download/preview/) has "infinite scroll", so you can view all the data.

[image]

Comment: That is nice. You can now both filter and sort by each column too.

Comment: @DavidArenburg Revamped code completion feature is great, too.

Answer (score 6):

It is not View() but also works in command-line R:

```
options(max.print=25000)
```

Printing is set to 25000 lines now.

Answer (score 3):

`utils::View(df)` will print everything also in Rstudio (Though this is not using the native Rstudio viewer, we will have to wait for the next version of Rstudio for that)

Answer (score 1):

I don't think it's possible to view more than 1000 rows at a time. However, if your goal is to view data beyond the 1000th row, you can subset your dataset, as follows:

```
View(df[2000:3000,]) # will show rows 2000-3000
View(df[5000:6000,]) # will show rows 5000-6000
```

Answer (score 1):

```
options(max.print=25000)
print.data.frame(<name_of_df>)
```