# R (rStudio): View error 'names' attribute [4] must be the same length as the vector [1] for character vector

Tags: r, data.table, rstudio

This has been happening recently, and I cannot understand how to resolve. N.B. I am using rStudio v0.99.893

I have created a character vector from a `data.table`, which I then attempt to View, and receive the above error:
`Error in View : 'names' attribute [4] must be the same length as the vector [1]`

The original DT has ~10,000 observations of 12 variables, here is a subset capturing all classes:

```
> head(DT, 3)
    HQ       URL      type  ID1 ID2  completion  date_first
1: imag image-welcome basic 444 24   0.1111111   2016-01-04 14:55:57 
2: imag image-welcome basic 329 12   0.2222222   2016-03-15 11:37:21
3: imag image-confirm int   101 99   0.1111111   2016-01-06 20:55:07

as.character(sapply(DT, class))
[1] "character"     "character"    "character"    "integer"    
[5] "integer"    "numeric"    "c(\"POSIXct\", \"POSIXt\")"
```

From `DT` I create a character vector of the unique values of `URL` for a subset of interest (only 'imag' HQ):

```
URL.unique <- unique(DT[HQ == "imag", URL])
> class(URL.unique)
[1] "character"

> names(URL.unique)
NULL

> View(URL.unique)
Error in View : 'names' attribute [4] must be the same length as the vector [1]

> length(URL.unique)
[1] 262
```

Printing `URL.unique` in the console works fine, as does exporting it via `write.table()` but it is annoying that I cannot view it.

Unless there is something implicitly incorrect about the above, I am resorting to reinstalling rStudio.  I've already tried quitting and relaunching, just in case there was some issue as I tend to leave multiple projects open on my computer over days.

Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: This sounds like something you should take up with Issue tracker on RStudio github page.

Comment: I doubt reinstalling will help; looks like a design decision/flaw they've made. You can probably `View(data.frame(u = URL.unique))` though.

Comment: You can also use `utils::View` as suggested by @gung's answer here http://stackoverflow.com/a/19346803

Comment: @Frank -- thanks for that, `View(data.frame(u = URL.unique))` is a sufficient workaround for the time being -- I tried `utils:View` and got an `xcrun: error: invalid active developer path...` I'll read more on the original post but you have given me a sufficient solution thus far -- shall I mark this as the 'answer'?

Comment: Hi from RStudio, we've filed an issue to investigate this (will keep you posted if we resolve it).

Comment: @Jonathan -- Appreciated, I resort to stackoverflow as my first response due to its efficiencies, good to know my 'rstudio' tag will attract the right eyes though.. :)

Comment: Hello again from RStudio! We think we have a fix for this in the dailies -- try build 1.1.2 or higher and let us know how it works out. https://dailies.rstudio.com/

Comment: If I'm understanding everything correctly, I'm seeing this in Docker `REPOSITORY: rocker/rstudio, TAG: latest, IMAGE ID: 403eaed10ba8` .  Any sense of when the fix will be visible in the Docker image?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As noted by @Jonathan, this is currently filed with RStudio to investigate.  Can confirm reinstalling and other measures did **not** resolve the issue which still persists.  If it is reproduced and filed as a bug, I would request @Jonathan to supply the details here for anyone else to tie into.

The workaround of `View(data.frame(u = URL.unique))` does the job to launch the viewer on the data object of interest (thanks @Frank)

Answer (score 1):

I am using `View(as.matrix(df$col_name))` and it seems to be working well.