# Why do the "DescTools" & "e1071" packages cause an error when trying to view lists containing dist objects?

Tags: r, listview, desctools, e1071

I have the following dataframe, 'A'. I calculate a distance matrix 'B' from it. Then I add that distance matrix 'B' to a list 'C' and view it.

```
A <- data.frame(x = c(1:10),
                y = c(21:30))

B <- dist(A)

C <- list(B)

View(C)
```

So far so good. No problems, all is well. But once I load either the package "DescTools" or "e1071" and perform the exact same actions, I get an error.

```
library("e1071")

A <- data.frame(x = c(1:10),
                y = c(21:30))

B <- dist(A)

C <- list(B)

View(C)
```

> Error in .Primitive("[")(x, 1:6, , drop = FALSE) :
> incorrect number of dimensions

However, when I directly call the list, or the distance matrix in the list, I still get a return without error:

```
C[[1]]
1         2         3         4         5         6         7         8         9
2   1.414214                                                                                
3   2.828427  1.414214                                                                      
4   4.242641  2.828427  1.414214                                                            
5   5.656854  4.242641  2.828427  1.414214                                                  
6   7.071068  5.656854  4.242641  2.828427  1.414214                                        
7   8.485281  7.071068  5.656854  4.242641  2.828427  1.414214                              
8   9.899495  8.485281  7.071068  5.656854  4.242641  2.828427  1.414214                    
9  11.313708  9.899495  8.485281  7.071068  5.656854  4.242641  2.828427  1.414214          
10 12.727922 11.313708  9.899495  8.485281  7.071068  5.656854  4.242641  2.828427  1.414214
```

What's also baffling me is that even if I unload the packages with detach(), the error remains.

```
library("DescTools")
detach("package:DescTools", unload=TRUE)

A <- data.frame(x = c(1:10),
                y = c(21:30))

B <- dist(A)

C <- list(B)

View(C)
```

Once I restart the session, and refrain from loading either package, it works again.

I tested all other packages I use. None cause this behaviour. I loaded the "e1071" package originally to use its kurtosis and skewness function. When I tracked down this error to this particular package, I eventually downloaded the "DescTools" package instead to avoid the error as it offers the same functions. However, it causes the same issue.

Is there some fix for this? Am I being stupid and there is something obvious I'm missing? I'm no programmer/coder/scripter, but usually I can piece together what I need from on here. I found nothing to help me with this though and this error is starting to get frustrating when I try to quickly check my lists. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not sure if this counts as an answer because I cannot solve your problem, but I think I can explain it.

If you use `utils::View(C)` instead of just `View(C)`, I run into the same error, *regardless of packages loaded*. According to [this comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19341853/r-view-does-not-display-all-columns-of-data-frame#comment28907119_19346803), RStudio provides its own viewer which can show lists and other stuff and overrules `View` unless called via the namespace `utils::View`. You also get this version of the function when you run your code in R outside of RStudio.

So apparently, loading the DescTools or e1071 packages also forces the use of the original View function because both import the `utils` package (which is usually already loaded by default in R).